# dynamic menus using catalyst

Tags: html, perl, drop-down-menu, catalyst

I'm having quite a hard time figuring out how to create two dynamic drop down menus.

I need to be able to populate the second drop down menu based on an item that was selected in the first drop down menu.  I can populate all data in both menus, but it's not the desired result.

Menu 1 with catalyst notation:

```
<select name="select_productsuiteid" required="yes" onChange="return setmode('selectProdSuite',this.form)">
  <option value="" selected="Selected">Please Select a Product Family</option>
  [% FOREACH prod_fam IN prod_fams %]
  <option value="[% prod_fam.fam_id %]">[% prod_fam.fam_name %]</option>
  [% END %]
</select>
```

Second menu with catalyst notation.  This is the menu that should populate with products based on a product family ID from the chosen product family in the first menu.

```
<select name="select_productid" required="yes" onChange="return setmode('selectProd',this.form)">
  <option value selected="selected">(no value)</option>
  [% FOREACH prod IN prods %]
  <option value="[% prod.prod_id %]">[% prod.prod_name %]</option>
  [% END %]
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can fill your first select the way you have in the template when you render, but what you want is a dynamic change. So you need JavaScript to do this.

Here is a link for [JavaScript Select](https://www.google.com.au/?q=javascript%20populate%20select%20options%20from%20another%20select#q=javascript%20populate%20select%20options%20from%20another%20select) as a google search. There are lots of options, so find the approach that suits you. Everything will range from writing your values into the page, to making AJAX requests.

Also when dealing with forms in Catalyst (or any other framework) it might be worthwhile to have a look at what [CPAN Modules](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Catalyst%20Form) may help you out a bit with your form handling.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out.  I was able to use `new Option` and plugin the correct value from catalyst.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being the final solution to my problem.  The JavaScript function is below and the HTML follows.  The js should be called from the primary menu of customers.  The js in combination with catalyst can populate the second drop down menu of customer locations based on the customer ID.

```
function dispSites() {
console.log('dispSites called');
var custSelection = document.adminform.select_Customerid.value;
var siteIndex = 1 ;
document.adminform.select_Siteid.options.length = 0;
[% FOREACH vetSite IN cust_locs %]
if (custSelection == [% vetSite.loc_cust_id %]) {
    var siteName ="[% vetSite.loc_name %]" ;
    var siteId =[% vetSite.loc_id %] ;
    document.adminform.select_Siteid.options[siteIndex] = new Option(siteName,siteId);
    siteIndex++ ;
    console.log('Adding customer id:',custSelection,'Site id/name:', siteId, siteName);
}
    [% END %]
```

}

```
<select name="select_Customerid" id="select_Customerid" required="yes" onchange="dispSites(this.form)">
            <option value="" selected>Select customer</option>
            [% FOREACH cust IN custs -%]
            <option value="[% cust.cust_id %]">[% cust.cust_name %]</option>
            [% END -%]
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="tdright" ><b>*Site:</b></td>
        <td >
        <select name="select_Siteid" id="select_Siteid" required="yes" >
            <option value="" selected>Select site</option>
            [% FOREACH loc IN cust_locs -%]
            <option value="[% loc.loc_id %]">[% loc.loc_name %]</option>
            [% END -%]
        </select>
```